# Mutating a Prop in Vue JS outside component

Tags: vue.js

This is my first Vue app so go easy on the code :P

I have a list of users on one side and a component to edit those user details on the other. When selecting a user you see their details and can then click 'edit details'. I want to hide the edit details and show the user details when a new user is selected. Inside the component, I have a ShowEdit variable that is true or false and will either show or hide the edit area. I am sending a prop from the parent into this component when a new user is selected to hide the edit if it is open. I feel I am close as it is currently working perfect but I would like to get rid of the error

> "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders...."

Here are the important bits:

Home

```
<transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
     <sidebar-client-content :theClient="selectedUser" :showEditHP="showEditHP"></sidebar-client-content>
</transition>

activate: function(el) {
    this.showEditHP = true // Hide edit if new user selected
},
```

Component

```
<div id="sidebar-client-content">
<div class="staff_header">
    <a v-if="showEdit" v-on:click="showEdit = !showEdit"><i class="fal fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>
    <a v-if="!showEdit" v-on:click="showEdit = !showEdit"><i class="far fa-times"></i>Close</a>
</div>
<transition-group name="fadeHeight" mode="out-in">
    <div class="client_information" v-if="showEdit">
           <!-- The Client Details -->
    </div>
    <div class="client_information" v-if="!showEdit">
        <!-- Client Edit Form -->
    </div>
</transition-group>
</div>



export default {
props: [
    'showEditHP', // Close edit if new user selected
],
computed: {

    showEdit: {
        get: function() {
            return this.showEditHP
        },
        set: function (newValue) {
            this.showEditHP = newValue
        }
    }

},
```

I understand the `this.showEditHP = newValue` line is where I make the edit but I can't seem to get it to work any other way. I want the parent to be able to overwrite it as the error says. Is there a way to achieve this and have the error removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nguyun said you can use `$emit` to send the value back to your parent to keep the values in sync. You can only change your parent data with emit otherwise it will just remain either true or false while the child continues to make it's changes. Keep the values in sync with emit and then use watch to check if the parent makes it's change.

```
<transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
     <sidebar-client-content @clicked="onClickChild" :theClient="selectedUser" :showEditHP="showEditHP"></sidebar-client-content>
</transition>

onClickChild (value) {
    // I am the child value inside the parent!
},
```

Then in the child

```
<div class="staff_header">
     <a v-if="showEdit" v-on:click="showEdit = !showEdit; $emit('clicked', showEdit)"><i class="fal fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>
     <a v-if="!showEdit" v-on:click="showEdit = !showEdit; $emit('clicked', showEdit)"><i class="far fa-times"></i>Close</a></i>Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is really clear

In your child component, you're trying to mutate the value of `showEditHP`:

```
set: function (newValue) {
    this.showEditHP = newValue
}
```

However, this kind of mutating is discouraged. Instead, we should `emit` an event from the child component and then let the parent component listen to that event and mutate the property itself.

In other words, the property `showEditHP` belongs to the parent component, well then the parent component should be the one which mutates it.

Comment: The parent is doing the changes but I can't get it to pass it as a prop and implement the new value to the child component.As Husam said below I can pass it and make it local but It doesn't work even when I implement his code. THoughts?